# alter .dropdown-content formatting to fit specific buttons using id in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a splash page with 3 dropdown buttons that I'm editing.  Each of them is based on a specific color that represents a geological time period. I want the .dropdown-content formatting for each button to be different & to reflect this base color. When I try to use the id tag to alter each button's '.dropdown-content' attributes, it breaks the code.  Here is the 'broken' css:

```css
.dropbtn {
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#left.dropbtn {
  border-color: #f57a5f;
  background-color: rgba(245, 122, 95, 0.2);
}

#middle.dropbtn {
  border-color: #9DC2A6;
  background-color: rgba(157, 194, 166, 0.2);
}

#right.dropbtn {
  border-color: #47C7EA;
  background-color: rgba(71, 199, 234, 0.2);
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
#left.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f57a5f;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

#middle.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #9DC2A6;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

#right.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #47C7EA;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: rgba(157, 194, 166, 0.2)}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover #left.dropbtn {
  background-color: #f57a5f;
}

.dropdown:hover #middle.dropbtn {
  background-color: #9DC2A6;
}

.dropdown:hover #right.dropbtn {
  background-color: #47C7EA;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h2><t id="the">The</t> Wowsers</h2>
      <p>Revealing stuff & knowledge & things</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button id="left" class="splashMainButton btn btn-info dropbtn">Learn</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="">Teach & Learn</a>
              <a onclick="">News & Info</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button id="middle" class="splashMainButton btn btn-info dropbtn">Data</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="">Enter</a>
              <a href="">Visualize</a>
              <a href="">Retrieve</a>
              <a href="s">Browse</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button id="right" class="splashMainButton btn btn-info dropbtn">Join & Support</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="">Join!</a>
              <a onclick="">Patreon!</a>
              <a onclick="">Merch</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do I have the nomenclature wrong in css?  Do I need to add an id to the  for each .dropdown-content?

Answer (score 1):

You need a space after each ID, e.g.:

```
#middle .dropdown-content
```

Because .dropdown-content is a *child* of #middle.

Without a space, it means the element with both an ID of middle *and* a class of dropdown-content.

Also, ID's are (or at least should be) unique, so you don't need to do this:

```
#left.dropbtn
```

You can target the element with just the `#left` selector.